# extracting filename and getting " GLOB<0x486a8> in perl

Tags: perl, filenames, glob

I am trying to extract my file name but I keep getting GLOB<0x486a8> as the file name? I've looked at multiple answers to questions answering similar questions but I still can't seem to solve my issue. The files i'm opening are standard fasta files with the following format where the first line contains the sequence information and the lines that follow are the sequences.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#open files from data directory
opendir my $data_dir, "data" or die "Unable to open directory!";
my @files = readdir $data_dir;    #reading files into array

#Taking only files with .fa extention
my @fa_files = grep /[\.][f][a]$/, @files;
my @sorted_fa_files = sort @fa_files;
#Taking each .fa and reading description line

foreach (@sorted_fa_files) {
    open my $filehandle, "<", "data/$_" or die "Unable to open file!";
    while (<$filehandle>) {
        print "filename: $filehandle\n";
    }
}
```

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: `/[\.][f][a]$/` is a rather complicated way to write `/\.fa$/`. And the whole procedure with `opendir` and `readdir` is a complicated way of writing: `my @sorted = sort glob "data/*.fa"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is `"data/$_"` (at least before the while loop; you are overwriting `$_` in the while). `$filehandle` is a filehandle, not a filename.

You should avoid using `$_` for two different purposes like this; use lexical variables instead:

```
foreach my $filename (@sorted_fa_files){
    open my $filehandle,"<","data/$filename" or die "Unable to open file!";
    while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ){
        print "filename: data/$filename";
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response! I am a beginner if you can not tell!